# WPF Animation To dynamic value

Tags: wpf, animation, styles

I want show up a UserControl occasionally.

When the visibility of the UserControl is changed to visible, it should ease in in a moderate speed.

I figured out how to to this basically:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}" x:Key="MyStyleName">            
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>                                
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="0.0" To="200.0" Duration="0:0:1" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

This works fine.

In the real world application, I don't know the exact value of the Height property, because the UserControl is "hosted" in a Grid and the row height is set to "Auto".

I've tried to do a Binding to the TemplatedParent, doesn't work. A Binding to a RelativeSource doesn't work either.

Can anyone help me, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, animate a ScaleTransform in the control's RenderTransform:

```
<Style TargetType="UserControl">
    <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation To="1" Duration="0:0:1" 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```